# How to change kernel for a non booting OS

Tags: boot, grub, kernel

When I boot up everything is fine until I get to userware, then screen looks funny/not smooth and keyboard and mouse stop working, only a hard reset gets me out.

When I checked on next bootup, I saw something about ... not a bionic kernel ... so back at grub menu I found that it was booting up with a kernel from another OS in my system. AntiX OS'es kernel. How the hell did that happen. My current kernel is 5.3.0-53-generic and 51, but somehow it was booting up with 4.9.212-antix.1-amd64-smp and 4.9.221-antix.1-amd64-smp and two others of that variety. I am really buffled.

My question is how can I force kernel update or reinstall using chroot in a live session so that it can update itself in grub? And once im in how to remove the above mentioned references from its config?

I have several OSes in my system but this is just nuts.

Comment: seems like another install tree updated the grub options ... have you tried (in Elementary) "sudo update-grub" ???

Answer (score 0):

You can always run some lie distribution form usb stick and then use sudo update-grub command, or grub customizer https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Chroot system is easy, press e on the keyboard when you selected the proper linux entry in grub and then type

```
rd.break
```

press ctrl+x

```
mount -o remount, rw /sysroot/
chroot /sysroot/
update-grub
```